# what is a continuous covariate?

Tags: predictor

I have a height in cm covariate, and the study involves 15-21 people (depends on what response we are looking at). The data is repeating measures.

So,  that's 15-21 unique height measurements. Is this continuous?

Comment: If it is measurements in centimeters, then yes.

Comment: Even though variables like this can only be measured to the nearest centimeter in this case the variable can be treated as continuous.